# Как из из телефонного номера взять последние четыре цыфры добавочного номера?

Tags: powershell

Нужно из телефонного номера вырезать последние четыре цыфры добавочного номера и вставить их в аргемент ip телефон. Сам телефон записан так +7 495 xxxxxxx-xxxx.

Пробовал `-replace '*.-',''`, но без успешно:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "DC=omnicare,DC=int" -Filter "telephoneNumber -like '+7 495*'" -Properties telephoneNumber |
ForEach-Object {
    $User = $_

    $telephoneNumber = $User.telephoneNumber -replace '*.-',''
   

    Set-ADUser -Identity $User.DistinguishedName -Replace @{IPPhone=$IPPhoneNumber}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парочку способов как бы это сделал, в примере использовал стринг:

```
$telephoneNumber = "+7 495 1234567-8910"
```

---

Первый вариант, преобразовать в массив, используя разделитель `-` и использовать второй элемен массива с индексом **1**

```
$telephoneNumber.Split("-")[1]
```

> PS C:\Users\Root> $telephoneNumber.Split("-")[1]
> 8910

---

Второй вариант, удалить необходимое количество символов от начала строки, в данном случае 15

```
$telephoneNumber.Substring(15)
```

> PS C:\Users\Root> $telephoneNumber.Substring(15)
> 8910

---

Можно еще так же распечатать с конца 4 последних символа

```
$OFS=''; [string]$telephoneNumber[-4..-1]
#Вернуть OFS при необходимости, по умолчанию является пробелом
$OFS = " "
```

> $OFS=''; [string]$telephoneNumber[-4..-1]
> 8910

Для чего нужно менять системную переменную OFS. Связано это с тем, что строка преобразовывается в массив и печатаются элементы с конца строки, т.е. каждый элемент при печати будет на следующей строке, поэтому мы тип данных `[string]` и меняем разделитель на пустоту, иначе получим элементы перечисленные через пробел `8 9 1 0`

Answer (score 0):

до кучи

```
(([regex]"\d{4}$").Matches("+7 495 1234567-8910")).Value
```

Для решения данной задачи можно использовать регулярные выражения.
[Регулярные выражения](http://%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F.%20%20%20%20%20https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%20%22%5Cd%7B4%7D$%22%20%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%20%E2%80%9C%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%E2%80%9D%20%20%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83,%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20(%5Bregex%5D%E2%80%9C%5Cd%7B4%7D$%E2%80%9D)%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%20%E2%80%9CSystem.Text.RegularExpressions%E2%80%9C,%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%20Matches%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%20%E2%80%9DMatch%E2%80%9D,%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC,%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%20%E2%80%9CValue%E2%80%9D%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82.)

Паттерн "\d{4}$" означает “точно четыре цифры за которыми идет окончание строки”

Обращение к объекту в скобках позволят обратиться к создаваемому объекту сразу, без его объявления ([regex]“\d{4}$”) получаем объект “System.Text.RegularExpressions“, обращаемся к его методу Matches получаем экземпляр класса ”Match”, в котором содержаться строки совпадающие с шаблоном, заключаем его в скобки и забираем свойство  “Value” профит.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). // возьмите за образец хотя бы предыдущий ответ.

Comment: Устали вы уже меня...

Comment: если движок классифицирует слишком многие ваши ответы как низкокачественные, помещая их в соответствующую очередь проверки, возможно, это повод к написанию более подробных ответов.